# Problem with deploying IntelliJ war file build with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using the simple IntelliJ web project with the default configuration.

I don't see any servlet mapping in the web.xml file:

[web.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN99y.png)

However, when I run the project in IntelliJ it just works fine:

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx5dE.png)

But when I build it as a war file and deploy it with my tomcat server I can't access the hello-servlet.
Why Local IntelliJ tomcat server works even without proper servlet-mapping on the web.xml file and why it does not work on the tomcat server when I copy the war file into webapps directory.

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use? Do you see any errors in Tomcat logs?

Comment: I am using tomcat version 8.5.81 and java 17.0.3.1 in both environments.
Also there is no error in tomcat logs it just gives me 404.